# How do I triage question with [SOLVED] and the author didn't post the answer?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, triage

This question appeared in the triage:

[Java program still running even after FTP connection closed [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513531/java-program-still-running-even-after-ftp-connection-closed-solved)

This **might** be an adequate question if the author shares the answer to their own problem. Right now it feels like it should be closed, but I'm unsure how.

**Obs.:** the author stated that the error was not in the question. So it should be probably closed as "not reproducible." However, as a general rule for future reference, let us pretend the error **was** in the code. What's the appropriate close reason? **If** it's:

- **not** MCVE;
- **not** "non-reproducible";
- **definitely not** "Requires Editing"; and
- absolutely positively, 100% sure **not** "Looks ok"...

...then all it seems left to me is "Skip". But sooner or later someone will have to act on it. So how?

Comment: The author did supply an explanation, but also states the error is not in the code. "Not reproducible" ought to be a good close reason, then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just handle it, since the author has not solved the problem:

- If a close reason applies: Close it
- If it is just a bad question: Open the question and downvote. [It will be removed automatically after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/292385).
- If it is a good question:

  - Looks OK
  - Edit the [SOLVED] part out of the question
  - Leave a comment encouraging the author to post an answer

Comment: Even if the author (or someone else) has solved the question, putting *[SOLVED]* in a title is a convention used on forum and bulletin board sites being coerced into acting as Q&A format sites. Stackoverflow is a Q&A site and doesn't need workarounds to pretend to be a Q&A site, so it should always be cut.

Answer (score 2):

[Christian Gollhardt's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341069/2615940) and the comments on it have good information, but I have a couple issues with the phrasing:

> Just handle it, since the author has not solved the problem

Whether or not the author solved the problem is irrelevant. Questions are judged on *solely* on their own merit, regardless of whether or not a resolution is posted. Saying "since the author..." is misleading and incorrect.

The same comment applies to the [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341068/2615940):

> This might be an adequate question if the author shares the answer to their own problem.

The user providing an answer does not make the question okay. If any of the close reasons apply, then flag or vote to close. If they don't, then edit or vote as you see fit and move on.

From [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341068/how-do-i-triage-question-with-solved-and-the-author-didnt-post-the-answer?cb=1#comment429711_341069):

> It's about the case, when the author marks his question [solved], but provides no solution

It's not a special case. It's exactly the same as if there had been no "[solved]" in the title or a solution *had* been posted.

**Short Answer**
Questions should *never* have any meta-information in the title, such as "[solved]" in the title. Edit it out and conduct your review as if it had never been there.

Answer (score 1):

"No longer reproduced" seems to be perfect close reason for this case. Unless problem is extremely valuable and unlikely duplicate - closing as such will not lose any information.

Close reason explicitly highlight that option:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers....

Maybe OP made mistake in they MCVE or it was not MCVE to start with. Unless you do know that this will be valuable for future visitors in current state there is usually not much can be done for that such "solved" question without OP.

If encouraging OP to post solution did not work you can copy whole question and take ownership of it that way if you find it valuable. This way you know what is asked, how to clarify/improve question if needed and can control what is considered "valid" answer.

Comment: How does knowing that the OP solved the problem mean that the problem isn't reproducible, or that the post doesn't contain enough information to reproduce it?

Comment: @Servy: OP admitted as much in a now edited-out remark: "Solution: The code runs in a JavaFX application, and the program didn't stop because in order to do that I should have opened and closed the main Window" This apparent reason was not in the original question (although it could be edited in now). ".. There was nothing wrong in the code." There you go.

Comment: @Servy at that point post is not practical - yes it may contain MCVE for *some* problem, but no one yet encountered problem specified in that MCVE (as clearly OP is not the one). To my understanding non-practical questions are not really welcome on SO as there is no value to answer them or keep around. To me closing "no longer reproduced" is reasonable.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not saying that you shouldn't close a question if it doesn't have a reproducible example, just that a question not having a reproducible example is a separate concern from the issue the meta question raises, which is specifically the author saying that they've found a solution (but not posting it).  As other answers have said, if the post merits closure for any reason unrelated to that, vote/flag to close accordingly.

Comment: @Servy my (controversial) claim here is it is ok close post as "no repro" even if it has valid MCVE because particular MCVE is no longer represent real problem. Indeed if there are good reasons to keep open/close differently - one should act on them.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Again, someone saying, "I solved the problem" doesn't automatically meant that the question didn't reproduce the problem, it just means that they found a solution for the problem they presented.  If the question didn't originally have enough information to reproduce the problem in the first place then them saying, "I found the answer" still doesn't change what you do.